# High side current sensing in BLDC motor?

Tags: operational-amplifier, current-measurement, brushless-dc-motor, current-sensing

I want to measure DC current flow through the 48 V battery in bldc motor (through Inverter circuit). Are [INA 282](http://www.ti.com/product/INA282), [INA 169](http://www.ti.com/product/INA169) work properly or not? Since my battery motor specification is 48 V, 5 Amp, 250 Watt

Previously, I used [ACS 712](https://www.electronicscomp.com/acs712-5amp-range-current-sensor-module?gclid=CjwKCAjw7tfVBRB0EiwAiSYGMwGuonTRZCJxUNux_rmC0E8UX9xF4yjH1aH3N1LSi0aiMcLNwRAjVhoClFcQAvD_BwE) current hall sensor but it nor worked. Its reading was totally absurd.

If any one have any idea regarding this, please help me.

Comment: Ac712 is a very good sensor, although with some noise. If it looks absurd to you, maybe you should first understand what are you expecting to see.

Comment: All three options, including the ACS712 should work. I think you should figure out why the ACS712 wasn't working for you before you give up.

Comment: I have used multi-meter and ACS712 both simultaneously but ACS712 reading was very far away from multimeter reading.

Comment: I have used the ACS712 also, and had no problems. Also, it is mass produced. If it didn't work, nobody would buy it and they would stop making it.

Comment: What I am trying to say is, you must have made a mistake. Instead of assuming that the part doesn't work, you should investigate what the actual problem was. Maybe a wiring mistake, maybe the part got damaged at some point, etc.

Comment: I want to use INA169, but its current range is only 3.5 mA-35mA. How can I increase the current range rating? Can I simlpy disolder the 10 ohm resistance Rs.